# QWidget::find(hwnd) always returning 0

Tags: qt, find, hwnd, qwidget

I'm grabbing a window handle with the following code:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(L"QWidget", NULL);
```

and it returns a HWND to a QWidget (I checked with Spy++, the handles match).
But after this, if I try the following:

```
QWidget* widget = QWidget::find(hwnd);
```

or

```
QWidget* widget = QWidget::find((WId)hwnd);
```

widget is always 0. Does anyone know why? Am I using QWidget::find() correctly?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:
was compiling in debug, so QtGui4d.dll was loaded instead of QtGui4.dll